# how to detect what triggered an android sdk onCameraChange call

Tags: android, google-maps, sdk

I have an application that tracks current location (using LocationListener), continually updating LatLngBounds to keep the track in view.  Every time the boundary change causes the map to be redrawn this makes a call to 'onCameraChange'

I want to temporarily halt this process when the user manually expands the map but to do this I need to be able to differentiate between a call to onCameraChange caused by the new LatLngBounds and a call to onCameraChange caused by the manual expansion of the map.

At the moment the onCameraChangeListener is started during the onCreate process.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a code similar to [this issue comment #21](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4636#c21).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for that, it pointed me in the direction to solve the problem.

As it happens, I only want to capture manual input when the user expands the map and so it was quite easy to check the zoom level whenever onCameraChange is called.  If the zoom passed by OnCameraChange is greater than the currently recorded zoom then I can be reasonably sure that the user expanded it as a LatLngBounds change will only reduce the zoom level.